# Why not create a latent heat battery?

Tags: electrochemistry

Since latent heat is not sensible, it seems like it would be useful in creating an efficient battery. Sensible heat interferes with electron flow in standard lead-acid and other batteries. The latent heat-electron interface might occur separately from the energy storage. Has this idea been explored?

Of course, I may be incorrectly assuming that latent heat does not itself add resistance to an electric circuit...

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022072894037025

Comment: Maybe! The discussion is inaccessible to me but it appears there may be a state change involved. The part about the interaction of H2O w/ an ion is intriguing.